# Elixir HTTP close connection error with Hackney {error: :closed}

Tags: elixir, tesla

I am facing strange issue in my elixir app which is using Tesla as http client and Hackney as adaptor.

While making HTTP calls to external server, it intermittently result in error --> error: :closed.
My application run inside pod and having istio sidecar proxy.
I am using elixir 1.10, Tesla 1.3.3, hackey 1.15, Erlang/OTP 22.

Below is the configuration I am using to make post calls.
Is anybody faced this issue and if yes then how he fixed it. What changes I should do to fix this intermittent issue.

```
hackney_options =
  if(insecure,
    do: [recv_timeout: timeout, ssl_options: [verify: :verify_none]],
    else: [recv_timeout: timeout]
  )

adapter = {Tesla.Adapter.Hackney, hackney_options}

client =
  headers
  |> middlewares(timeout, retry, should_retry)
  |> Tesla.client(adapter)
```

Comment: `ssl_options: [verify: :verify_none]`
are you trying to access https?

Comment: yes I am hitting HTTPS url.

Comment: There is also an open issue but not sure if it is related to how i do configuration https://github.com/benoitc/hackney/issues/630

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem. Did you ever figure out a solution? Thanks.

Comment: No. I was not able to find any solution. I did packet tracing and confirm that it was an issue at my elixir application and not in the network or the other side. One thing I observe that it happen when load is high for continuous long time. So if your application is handling 100 or few 1000's of connection you may not notice this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the additional details. We were able to pinpoint this to the connection pool in Hackney. Once we disabled pooling, the error went away.

Comment: What changes you made at connection? As I remember it has some default connection pool (other than hackney) setup but it is advisable not to use it. I also tried disabling same but  that also did not solve my problem instead it brings issue counts to some less value. But at the same time it did not check for expire https certificate (as I remember).

Comment: We're not using tesla, but HTTPoison. So, I simply passed `[hackney: [pool: false]]` to the request and that prevents the request from using the `default` pool.

Comment: Correct I also used the thing.